# Python, export dependencies

Tags: python, jenkins

Is there any easy way to export the libs my script needs so that I can put all of the files into a git repo and run the script from Jenkins without the need of installing anything?

context:
   remote Jenkins without some python libs (RO - no access to terminal)
   need to run my script that needs external libs such as paramiko, requests, etc

I have tried `freeze.py` but it fails at make stage

I have found some articles here regarding `freeze.py`, `p2exe`, `p2app`, but none of those helped me.

Comment: So you cannot install anything with pip during your build?

Comment: Python has a good module that you can build an executable file from your application along with your module: `python-distutils`

Comment: Rob Cowie - no, I can not install anything during build since the fs is read only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to install your required python dependencies in the workspace. In short, this sets up a local version of python and pip for which you can install packages without affecting the system installation. Using virtual environments is also a great way to ensure dependencies from one job do not impact other jobs. This solution does require [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to be installed on the build machine.

Your build step should do something like:

```
virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
# ... perform build, tests ...
```

If you separate your build into several steps, the environment variables set in the `activate` script will not be available in subsequent steps.  You will need to either source the `activate` script in each step, or adjust the `PATH` (e.g. via [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)) so that the virtualenv python is run.